# Why is Xcode 7.3 showing a slash through the app icon when attempting to install on Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, xcode, install

I am running Xcode 7.2.1 on my Mac mini running Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and recently wanted to compile an Apache Cordova project and install it on my iPhone 6s running iOS 9.3 and discovered I couldn’t. The error message that comes up in Xcode is “Could not find Developer Disk Image” which I discovered basically means, “Time to get a new version of Xcode!”

So I went to the [downloads area of the Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/), downloaded [the disk image of Xcode 7.3](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3/Xcode_7.3.dmg) opened it up and saw this in the Finder window for the Xcode disk image pictured below. What the heck is happening?

[image: Screenshot of the Xcode disk image being opened with the slash through the Xcode icon.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that Xcode 7.3 requires Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) or higher to run see screenshot below from the Mac App Store but the same idea for either install method.

Oh well. Been nice knowing you Yosemite!

As one can see [from this question I posted a little while back](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208801/40457) I’m fairly cautious with my core OS upgrades so I jumped to Mac OS X 10.10 when El Capitan was released just to not be too far behind the curve. Now, I guess I need to finally make the jump to El Capitan!

[image: Screenshot of the Xcode download page with requirement details.]

Comment: that's actually the SDK, not the minimum OS, but yes, min OS is generically "10.11 or later" https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

Comment: I downloaded 7.3 but its still not showing 9.3 under ios target version, since my phone is 9.3 i cant deploy my 9.2 app anymore cus it says no disk image found